# Block User account Control GPO on PC

Tags: group-policy

I am a local administrator on my win 8 PC which is on a domain. In order for the Win 8 apps to work I need to have both UAC and the firewall enabled. They are being disabled by a domain GPO. Is it possible to block these two from disabling?

From C:/gpresults.html

```
Computer Details
    Settings
        Policies
            Windows Settings
                Security Settings


                    User Account Control

Policy  Setting Winning GPO
User Account Control: Admin Approval Mode for the Built-in Administrator account    Enabled Disable Firewall Service
User Account Control: Behavior of the elevation prompt for administrators in Admin Approval Mode    Elevate without prompting   Disable Firewall Service
User Account Control: Detect application installations and prompt for elevation Disabled    Disable Firewall Service
User Account Control: Run all administrators in Admin Approval Mode Disabled    Disable Firewall Service
```

Comment: Methods have. The problem is that you will go through a security hole in your organization. Try to go the official route and describe the problem to the system administrator for your organization.

Comment: You would need Administrator permission on the domain in order to do this.  Being a local Administrator is meaningless if you are on a domain and are not an Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the Group Policies are to ensure the security and consistency for the whole enterprise. Having local admin rights does not supersede that requirement and therefore not only can you not do this, you shouldn't be trying since in doing so, you are probably breaking your terms of use and possibly your terms of employment.

Instead, contact your enterprise IT support team and explain to them what you require.